# Getting data using queues in laravel 5.4 + dynamically displaying it in proper module after that

Tags: php, ajax, rest, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

Im building application in Laravel 5.4 that is composed from several "modules" just tables with data from database and from external APIs. Im using Eloquent to getting data from database and Guzzle for calls APIs.

My problem is that I dont know how to get this data in in background (queues or what should I use) then just refreshing proper module and again and again after some set time or when there will be error in call to APIs... 
It needs to be ~real time.

And there will be more users login into the application. 
Should I maybe use a cache or some local database for storing that data?

How to inject ready data into template? (Blade cannot work dynamically) Some AJAX or what do you sugest?

Any ideas or advices which technologies to use for that?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I used VueJS with sockets in here to take this data realtime from endpoints with broadcasting.

And used crawler with supervisor and queues to retrive this data every minute in my case.